# Wordpress doubling articles posted to front page

Tags: wordpress

I have no background in html or php programming. Some in c#. I was asked to help a friend with a news site that was made using wordpress. What is happening is on the front page news are added in your typical news site fashion of small quadratic window divisions going in order across the site but when they reach the last little window and go below into a list order the first of the list order repeats the last of the little "window" articles.
If anyone has any idea what is wrong please let me know.

Comment: post your code please

Comment: post the code of your template index.php

Comment: I don't have access to the code in the sense that the guy who built the page has it on his servers (its like he gives domains out for free if u get him to build it) and i can't reach him at the moment but i will try and see what i can do